# Conversion of Classic Website to Google Sites

Tags: google-sites

My organization missed the planned conversion date  to the new Google Site in 2021. We are now unable to edit our classic website as a result. We would like to keep the domain name and convert it to the new Google sites for editing. Can we still get the conversion done, and if so, what is the systematic process?

We sought to convert our classic website to Google Sites for editing but such option was not available.